# JavaScript: replace three spaces with html 160 entity after XMLSerializer incorrectly parses entities

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I'm trying to do something like this...

```
f = f.replace('   ',' &#160; ','gi');
```

I've also tried this...

```
f = f.replace(/\ {3,}/g,' &#160; ','gi');
```

How do I replace three spaces with the entity above?

Using `\s` does not work, I've gone through plenty of other Q&As on Stack and nothing has worked.

For clarification this problem stems from `XMLSerializer()` parsing in addition to serializing and the spaces are at the beginning of each sentence. I use this to make code human readable when editing.

Example placeholder text in the XHTML editor (just a textarea)...

```
 <p>1
 &#160; 2
 &#160; 3
 &#160; 4
 &#160; 5</p>
```

...the goal is to serialize this code and either retain the entities (serialization should not parse but all the browsers do) or to "de-parse" by replacing the after-effects.

Also the variable f is a string, not an object or fragment in example.

**IMPORTANT!**

After using encodeURI turns out these aren't spaces being generated by `XMLSerializer()`, (spaces added to make this more readable) `%0A` `%20` `%C2` `%A0` `%C2` `%A0`.

---

Here are a couple examples of what the text looks like before and after using encodeURI to determine what the characters were since they weren't matching spaces thus throwing people off who were trying to help...

```
%0A%20&#160;&#160;First%20and

&#160;&#160;First and
```

The first has two entities inserted, not desirable, I just need one.

```
&#160; Which is actually

%0A%20&#160;%20Which%20is%20actually
```

The second output works great using the following from @Bergi...

```
f = f.replace(/\u00a0/g, '&#160;')
```

---

The following are the unsuccessful attempts with the last one being the successful attempt...

```
//f = f.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'');
//f = f.replace('   ',' &#160; ','gi');
//f = f.replace( / {3,}/g, '&#160;' );
//f = f.replace(/ {3,}/g,' \u00a0 ');
//f = f.replace(/\ {3,}/g,' &#160; ');
f = f.replace(/ \u00a0/g, ' &#160;');
```

Comment: Doesn't `replace` only take 2 parameters?

Comment: What does `f` look like?

Comment: You should use `replace` with only with the [two standard parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace). Anyway, `ignorecase` makes no sense for whitespaces, and your regex already has the `global` flag.

Comment: @John Now you've edited the question to show us what you _have_. Please also edit it to show us what you _want_, as if "If I were going to type the raw HTML source for my result into a text editor, what would I type?"

Comment: Please show us the code - which input you have, how you read it into JS, and how you set the output (textarea).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of replacing with an entitiy, replace with the actual character:

```
 f = f.replace(/ {3,}/g,' \u00a0 ');
```

Of course that depends on the output of that string, but usually you should use a string as it should be.

BTW: To make html/xml whitespaces readable, I'd recommend the css property `white-space:pre-wrap` instead of inserting non-breaking characters. They especially make copying the text a horror. Also, if your desire is to show as many whitespaces as in the source, you should replace `/\s{2}/` with `" \u00a0"`.

---

OK, you have a very curious input: linebreak (`10`, `%0A`, `"\n"`), a normal space (`32`, `%20`, `" "`) and two non-breaking spaces (`160`, `%C2%A0`, `"\u00a0"`). What you could do now to get the desired output:

- replace the first nbsp with its entity and the second with a blank: `replace(/\u00a0{2}/g, "&#160; ")`
- replace only the first of two adjacent nbsp: `replace(/\u00a0(.)/g, "&#160;$1")`
- replace three whitespaces with two blanks and a entity between: `replace(/\s{3}/g, " &#160; ")`

Comment: That would do the opposite of what I'm trying to do.

Comment: What exactly *are* you trying to do? You want to show the user a bunch of entities?

Comment: Sentences are properly typed with two spaces between. For human readable editing I use a line-break and then [space][entity 160][space].

Comment: And what exactly does not work? How do you set the value of your editor textarea?

Comment: Using encodeURI turns out these aren't spaces, (spaces added to make this more readable) %0A %20 %C2 %A0 %C2 %A0. Keep in mind this is from serialization output.

Comment: So, you want to `replace(/\u00a0/g, "&#160;")`?

Comment: SUCCESS! It gives me doubles 160 entities on some lines. Give me a moment to work out the details...

Comment: I've updated the bottom of the post to show two examples where it double-generates the entity. I only want all lines to start with a single instance. I'll accept your answer, if you can please update it (at the very extreme end of my day now) and help me get it totally working I'll up-vote it too. Thanks for your help and patience.

Comment: I think I got it now. You should be able to build your own regex / replacestring now if the format still does not match.

Answer (score 2):

```
var f = "Hello      World";
f = f.replace( / {3,}/g, '&#160;' );
console.log(f);
// "Hello&#160;World"
```

It smells like your problem has nothing to do with the string replacement, but how you are using that to modify your HTML. What are you doing for that?

**Edit**: If you want the user to actually *see* `&#160;` in the browser, then you need:

```
f = f.replace( /\s+{3,}/g, '&amp;#160;' );
```

### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wrMMy/

Comment: @John OK, great. So what _are_ you doing?

Comment: Tried, sorry no dice. Keep in mind that the spaces are at the beginning after a line break and not in the middle of text.

Comment: @John I've just showed you that this works. Your problem lies outside of your string replacement, and what you are _doing_ with it. This is what we need to know, to help you. What is your actual code to use `f` after the result?

Comment: Alright, I've updated this. I've encountered this problem before when trying to write directly to the DOM and I got around it by working with a string. Thing is variable f *IS* a string so I'm not sure how with f being a string to start with and then receiving code and then thirdly having regex work (@Hugo's code work on jsfiddle but not in my code) means something is screwy.

Comment: @John Hugo's works because you are seeing the string contents in an alert box, where HTML is not interpreted. If you wrote `alert('<b>hi</b/>')` it would not appear in bold, you would see the markup. Similarly, when you alert the string `"&#160;"` you see the entity. However, when you inject that string into the web browser as HTML, it becomes an invisible whitespace character.

Comment: Using encodeURI turns out these aren't spaces, (spaces added to make this more readable) %0A %20 %C2 %A0 %C2 %A0. Keep in mind this is from serialization output.

Comment: Up-voting, was on-topic before I mentioned the serialization.

Answer (score 1):

```
f = f.replace(/\ {3,}/g,' &#160; ');
```

That works.  `replace` takes just two arguments.
Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SjydF/

Comment: No need to escape the space in the regex.

Comment: That works there but no in my code. Variable f is a string and not a fragment although coming from serialization.

Comment: Using encodeURI turns out these aren't spaces, (spaces added to make this more readable) %0A %20 %C2 %A0 %C2 %A0. Keep in mind this is from serialization output.

Comment: Up-voting, was on-topic before I mentioned the serialization.